# Customize the field.html file for Sprout Forms

Tags: templating, plugin-sproutforms

I've set up a Spout Form, and I can customize the form.html file after copying it and moving it to my own `templates/_form/formHandle` folder. But when I want to customize the `field.html` file (I do the exact same thing as with the `form.html` file) nothing happens. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I only want to add some custom classes, nothing fancy :-).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override `field.html` you will also have to provide an override for `tab.html` and `errors.html`.

The `field.html` template is a bit more complex and the Twig code to get it to work depends on a few other files to work properly.

I've updated the documentation to better reflect this requirement: [Template Overrides](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/template-overrides)

---

If you only need to update the classes, you may also want to consider [Rendering Options](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/rendering-options).

Rendering options would let you dynamically pass the class names to the underlying form code. Depending on how predictable your field names are, it could work like this:

```
{% set options = {
    "class": "form-class form-class-customized",
    "errorClass": "form-has-error",
    "fields": {
        "fieldHandle": {
            "class": "my-fancy-class",
            "errorClass": "field-has-error",            }
    }
} %}

{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm("formHandle", options) }}
```

Comment: That did the trick for adding classes :-)! Still gonna go dig into the template overrides in the html files too, since I'm probably gonna need it later on too. Thanks for the answer!